# How to check if Image file is really included in Request in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an API using ExpressJS.In one of the endpoints I need to create an account with an optional avatar.

So, I want to upload the avatar if avatar was provided before creating an account, but if no avatar was provided I just want to go ahead and still create the account.

I have the following code to check if avatar exists but it always returns undefined even though available.

```
    createAccount: async (req, res) => {
        let avatar = req.file.avatar;
        if (avatar) {
            console.log("Avatar Found");   //Even when I include avatar, I still get undefined here;
        } else {
            console.log("No Avatar Found");
        }
    },
```

Comment: and if you console.log(req.file) & console.log(req) what is the output?

Comment: @StefanAvramovic when I console.log(req.file); is still shows No Avatar found

Comment: You need to show us the client code for uploading

Comment: `console.log(req.files)` and `console.log(req.files.avatar)`

Comment: If you are uploading a single file then  value of `req.file` is `avatar`, Just check `if(req.file == "avatar") {}`

if you are uploading array then req.files if the array with file names.